# Ruby - Selenium Webdriver , AngularJS Radiobutton Unable to detect Attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to detect the "checked" attribute on a radio button.

I have two radio buttons like this:
[Radio Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls8RI.png)

These are the element attributes:

```
<input type="radio" ng-change="logConsent(true)" ng-model="xxxConsent" value="true" id="xx_Summary_Radio_Consent_Yes" name="consent" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

and

```
<input type="radio" ng-change="logConsent(false)" ng-model="x2Consent" value="false" id="x2_Summary_Radio_Consent_No" name="consent" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

Using Selenium webdriver, `element.attribute('checked')` returns nil at all times. I do not understand how to check if its checked/enabled or not. I tried scanning for changes in Chrome inspect: the attributes do not change before and after checking the radio buttons. Can someone help me verify this?

Also to moderators/users ::I am not unable to correlate other 'radio button' issues and answers to  mine within StackOverflow though i can see lot of such questions. That's why I raised a separate Question.

Comment: Update :: The Element changes Class from -  `ng-valid ng-valid-required` :: to **`ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty`**.  But  what I noticed was once we try clicking yes and no both, both change state but do not refresh back to original state. What has this to do with checked property? [In the end both of them are ng-dirty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I can see the HTML has value attributes.

They should be something like using a event directive to keep count of such clicks and read off attribute value true and false  and generate the history you are talking about.

I believe you can try this - setup a event listener for ng-dirty ? or whichever it triggers. Check with the dev, they should be able to help. based on triggerd events you can detect that the click has worked well - atleast according to what you are describing. Here if you are able to read the value true false , then you are detecting a event and a HTML node attribute value - this sould confirm the click. Though you are not exactly verifying the checked attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As per provided HTML code, there is no checked attribute but you are trying to retrieve this. That is the reason its giving you null values. I hope as per HTML provided there is 'value' attribute with True for one and False for another. So i am expecting checked radio button have value = "True" so try value attribute.

In Java we can try like below

```
    myWebElement.getAttribute("value");  //this retrieve true or false

    // or we  can try like below also

    if(myWebElement.isEnabled() ==true){

        //my elemented is in selected state

    }
```

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Hi Murali, I am aware and tested with same - first thing actually. It always stays true for first one and false for second one. [Always, regardless of how many action]. Additional info - The window popup button on  right you see - gives a cumulative history of clicking of yes and no when the popup opens. essentially it stores somehow all actions and time performed of the clicks.